# Android Parcelable readStringArray bad array lengths

Tags: android, arrays, parcelable

Can you tell me how to solve this? It throws a bad array length exception and after debugging, I found this method throws the Exception:

```
--------------------------My Code-----------------------------------

public class SingleModels implements Parcelable{

    public String name;
    public String[] names ;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {

        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeStringArray(names);
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SingleModels> CREATOR = new Creator<SingleModels>() {

        @Override
        public SingleModels[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SingleModels[size];
        }

        @Override
        public SingleModels createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            SingleModels models = new SingleModels();
            models.name = source.readString();
            models.names = source.createStringArray();
            source.readStringArray(models.names);
            return models;}
    };
}
```

This is my exception, but so long, I can't upload the image, I cut the information by important:

```
07-07 09:52:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 09:52:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4296): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.single.parcelable.example/edu.single.parcelable.example.ArrayParcelable_Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths
07-07 09:52:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the implementation of `readStringArray()`:

```
public final void readStringArray(String[] val) {
    int N = readInt();
    if (N == val.length) {
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            val[i] = readString();
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("bad array lengths");
    }
}
```

So it seems as though the length of your `models.names` array is the reason it's throwing that error. You need to know the exact size of your array beforehand to create the array so that it doesn't throw the error.

I think `createStringArray()` suffices, you don't need to call `source.readStringArray(models.names);` so just delete that and it should work.

---

I think there may be a language barrier here, so i'll mention the exact code you should have:

```
@Override
    public SingleModels createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        SingleModels models = new SingleModels();
        models.name = source.readString();
        models.names = source.createStringArray();
        return models;
}
```

Comment: public SingleModels createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
   SingleModels models = new SingleModels();
   models.name = source.readString();
   models.names = new String[7];
            source.readStringArray(models.names);
   return models;
  }     and I set the StringArray length is OK

Comment: First, try to simply remove the line where you `readStringArray`, I don't think you need it at all.

Comment: I making createStringArray() at last,and call the readInt(),readInt() is Not Equal Array legth

Comment: Why are you calling `readInt`? All you have to do is remove `readStringArray` and your code should work.

Comment: that's right !!! thank you answer my question !

Comment: Awesome, that Helped!!! Thank You very much